# Can not access input text of Watson conversation

Tags: watson-conversation

I tried to access the user's input as described here: http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/advanced_overview.shtml based on the car-dashboard dialog.

```
{
  "output": {
    "text": "Great choice! Playing some @genre music for you.  <?input text?>"
  } 
}
```

Error:

`Dialog node error
Error when updating output with output of dialog node id:node_5_1469049934217. Fix the dialog node. Node output was:{"text":"Great choice! Playing some @genre music for you. "} org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos 6): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'text'`

Comment: it works with <?input_text?>, so documentation needs to  be updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access user input you can use the `input` object.

For example:

```
<? input.text ?>;
```

The following help page has more details under [accessing inputs](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/dialog_reference.shtml).